# Distribute horizontally in html when number of images in dynamic

Tags: javascript, html, css, angular

I have **buttons** inside a `div` container that I want to distribute horizontally in the container.
The number of buttons is dynamic according to the user permissions , so I can't use an hard coded percents or distance.

```
<div class="main-div" [align]="center">
<button mdbBtn class="sub-button" type="button" id="myButton1" accessKey=4 color="primary" size="lg" mdbWavesEffect align="middle">Add Customer1</button>
<button mdbBtn class="sub-button" type="button" id="myButton2" accessKey=3 color="primary" size="lg" mdbWavesEffect align="middle">Add Customer2</button>
<button mdbBtn class="sub-button" type="button" id="myButton3" accessKey=4 color="primary" size="lg" mdbWavesEffect align="middle">Add Customer1</button>
<button mdbBtn class="sub-button" type="button" id="myButton4" accessKey=2 color="primary" size="lg" mdbWavesEffect align="middle">Add Customer2</button>
</div>
```

In the following code - each button has an access level, in the init method of the component (written in angular), there is a function that checks if the button can be displayed to this user, according to the user permissions and the access level of this button, the init method set the x.style.display to "none" or "block" accordingly.

I want that only the displayed buttons will distribute horizontally in the container.
Does anyone have an idea how it can be done?

Thanks,
Osnat

Answer (score 0):

Can you please provide us some more details regarding the issue that you are facing. Provide us some code or something form which we can find some solution.How do want to hide the button using.

Is this is the solution you are looking for :

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<style>
  #myDIV {
    margin: 20px;
  }
</style>
</head>
<body>
    <button onclick="myFunction()">Try it</button>
    <button id="myDIV">Try it</button>

<script>
  function myFunction() {
    var x = document.getElementById("myDIV");
    if (x.style.display === "none") {
      x.style.display = "block";
    } else {
      x.style.display = "none";
    }
  }
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can leverage Flexbox CSS to do this.

If you use bootstrap, you can easily use:

```
<div class="main-div d-flex justify-content-between" [align]="center">
<button mdbBtn class="sub-button" type="button" id="myButton1" accessKey=4 color="primary" size="lg" mdbWavesEffect align="middle">Add Customer1</button>
<button mdbBtn class="sub-button" type="button" id="myButton2" accessKey=3 color="primary" size="lg" mdbWavesEffect align="middle">Add Customer2</button>
<button mdbBtn class="sub-button" type="button" id="myButton3" accessKey=4 color="primary" size="lg" mdbWavesEffect align="middle">Add Customer1</button>
<button mdbBtn class="sub-button" type="button" id="myButton4" accessKey=2 color="primary" size="lg" mdbWavesEffect align="middle">Add Customer2</button>
</div>
```

If not, then use add the CSS:

css

```
.d-flex {
  display: flex;
}

.justify-content-between {
  justify-content: space-between;
}
```

Or you might want to do:  `justify-content-around` if that is what you are looking for

check the documentation: https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.3/utilities/flex/#justify-content